# Duplicate Header component porting from standard React to Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I created a front-end using [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) and decided to move it to [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/). However, the component Header.js is displayed twice. Why does this happen?

[image]
[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import Header from "../Components/Header";
import ThirdMenu from "../Components/ThirdMenu";
import Sidebar from "../Components/Sidebar";
import Good from '../Components/Good';
import ListPages from '../Components/ListPages';
import BestSellers from '../Components/BestSellers';
import Customers from '../Components/Customers';
import Footer from '../Components/Footer';

const IndexPage = () => (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <ThirdMenu />

      <div className="Flex-container">
          <Sidebar />
          <Good />
      </div>
      <ListPages />
      <BestSellers />
      <Customers />
      <Footer />
      </div>

)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Its look like somewhere in router it added?Could you please check Header and router part

Comment: I not see routers in Header.js and anywhere:)

Comment: https://github.com/fpsstyle228/Portland.gts - repository on git,maybe help.

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby provides lots of functionality for templating and pages. For example, you will often see files in the `src/layouts` directory including an `index.jsx`. These files are [layout components](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-with-components/#layout-components).

Taking a look at your [GitHub repository](https://github.com/fpsstyle228/Portland.gts/), the layout file [`src/layouts/index.js`](https://github.com/fpsstyle228/Portland.gts/blob/e0e26107d69aede1020176de27f14a19d2bd720d/src/layouts/index.js) is including your Header as well as your [`src/pages/index.js`](https://github.com/fpsstyle228/Portland.gts/blob/e0e26107d69aede1020176de27f14a19d2bd720d/src/pages/index.js) file. You ought to delete one of them, most likely the `<Header />` in [`src/pages/index.js`](https://github.com/fpsstyle228/Portland.gts/blob/e0e26107d69aede1020176de27f14a19d2bd720d/src/pages/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

In `srr/layouts/index.js`  delete component header.